# Dropwizard Guice Error: Missing dependency for constructor

Tags: java, guice, jersey-2.0, dropwizard

I am working on a project which requires Guice integration with dropwizard. Following is the way I have designed it.

ApplicationClass

```
public class MyService extends Application<MyServiceConfig> {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new MyService().run(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(Bootstrap<MyServiceConfig> bootstrap) {
        GuiceBundle<MyServiceConfig> guiceBundle = GuiceBundle.<MyServiceConfig>newBuilder()
                .addModule(new MyServiceModule())
                .setConfigClass(MyServiceConfig.class)
                .enableAutoConfig(this.getClass().getPackage().getName())
                .build();

        bootstrap.addBundle(guiceBundle);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(MyServiceConfig config, Environment environment) throws Exception{

    }
```

This is the MyServiceModule which I wrote

```
public class MyServiceModule extends AbstractModule{
    @Provides
    public MyDataStoreInterface getDataStore(MyServiceConfig myServiceConfig){
        return new MyDataStore(myServiceConfig.getConfig1(), myServiceConfig.getConfig2());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure() {

    }
}
```

These are my data store files

```
public interface MyDataStoreInterface {
  public void method1();
}

public class MyDataStore implements MyDataStoreInterface {
  public MyDataStore(Config1 config1, Config2 config2){
    /*implementation*/
  }
  public void method1(){
    /*implementation*/
  }
}
```

And lastly following is my resource file

```
@Path("/documents")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class MyResource {
   private MyDataStoreInterface myDataStore;

   @Inject
   public MyResource(MyDataStoreInterface myDataStore) {
     this.myDataStore = myDataStore;
   }
}
```

When I run the above application I get the following error:

> ERROR [2016-04-27 20:34:29,669] com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors: The
>   following errors and warnings have been detected with resource and/or
>   provider classes:
>   SEVERE: Missing dependency for constructor public
>   com.mobile.myservice.resources.MyResource(com.mobile.myservice.datastore.MyDataStoreInterface)
>   at parameter index 0

Can someone help me where I am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you ever bind MyServiceConfig anywhere? What kind of Guice integration are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your problem is that dropwizard uses Jersey under the hood. Notice the exception is not about Guice but Jersey. Jersey and Guice need some tweaks working together. Jersey has its own DI framework ([HK2](https://hk2.java.net)). You need to bridge them.

**Edit**: Take a look at [`dropwizard-guicey`](https://github.com/xvik/dropwizard-guicey), a project aimed at your problem. Thanks to @pandaadb for the comment below.

Very quick code example:

```
@ApplicationPath("api")
public class ApiRest extends ResourceConfig {  
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ApiRest.class);

    @Inject
    public ApiRest(ServiceLocator serviceLocator, ServletContext servletContext) {
        log.debug("Inicialitzant Jersey.");
        packages("net.sargue.app.api");

        GuiceBridge.getGuiceBridge().initializeGuiceBridge(serviceLocator);
        GuiceIntoHK2Bridge guiceBridge = serviceLocator.getService(GuiceIntoHK2Bridge.class);
        Injector injector = (Injector) servletContext.getAttribute(Injector.class.getName());
        if (injector == null)
            throw new RuntimeException("Guice Injector not found");
        guiceBridge.bridgeGuiceInjector(injector);
    }
}
```

That will work for an standard Jersey / JAX-RS API. You probably would need to adjust to dropwizard.

See this question and my answer:

- [Jersey and Google Guice integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36555137/jersey-and-google-guice-integration)

Comment: In this case, there are integration frameworks that handle this for you. I am using https://github.com/xvik/dropwizard-guicey and I am extremely happy with it. This discovers and injects all jersey components (providers,filters,resources etc) automatically for me.